# Flutter - How to check is the app has a new version?

Tags: flutter

I create an app with **[Flutter](https://flutter.dev)**. I need to force users to update the app when I upload a new version. I try [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader), but I think that it doesn´t work. In the documentation, we can read that we can verify the version with this code.

```
Container(
     margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12.0, 0.0, 12.0, 0.0),
     child: UpgradeCard();
)
```

The problem is: I need to check the version in *'initState', not in **Scaffold**. So what is the right way to check the version on the app start?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I recommend trying out the [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config) and update the minimum required version there. It's not a good practice to force update app on every update in the store. Also, some users can see the updated version in given store later than others. This is just how Google Play and AppStore work.

Thus, when you really need to force update the application you can increment the parameter on Firebase e.g. a day after update in the store.

Simple code to trigger the dialog can look as following:

```dart
Future<bool> checkUpdates() async {
    await remoteConfig.fetch();
    await remoteConfig.activateFetched();

    final requiredBuildNumber = remoteConfig.getInt(Platform.isAndroid
        ? 'requiredBuildNumberAndroid'
        : 'requiredBuildNumberIOS');

    final currentBuildNumber = int.parse(packageInfo.buildNumber);

    return currentBuildNumber < requiredBuildNumber;
  }
```

This requires [package_info](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info) package to be added as well as [firebase_remote_config](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_remote_config).

To open the app in the store you need to use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package and just pass URL to your app.

Comment: will this work for android though, where build numbers are 1.0.1 etc?

Comment: You refer to build version. Build numbers are just integers.

Answer (score 6):

you can call `https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=$id` or `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$id` to receive the newest app version available on the stores.
i can recommend this package to do this: https://pub.dev/packages/new_version

Comment: how do we get latest version from these links?

Answer (score 3):

You can check your app version like

```
@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
Timer( 
    Duration(seconds: 3), // put your stuff here
        () => Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => LoginScreen())));}
```

and presume one thing this code must be in spalsh screen or home screen
and there you can check app version forcefully stop any app which is belonged old version

Comment: And how can i add UpgradeCard() inside this timer?

Comment: I try 

Timer( 
    Duration(seconds: 10),

    UpgradeAlert());


and return The argument type 'UpgradeAlert' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()'.

Comment: you have to match app version and current version of the app .

Answer (score 2):

Try out the **in app update package**- https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update which works on **Android** and for **iOS**, try- https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader.

Comment: It's not working on iOS.

Comment: For iOS- https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the current version number from the App Store and Play Store. You can use the [upgrader](https://pub.dev/packages/upgrader) package API like this:

EDIT: If your app is NOT available on the US App Store or Play Store, you need to change the country code.

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:html/dom.dart';
import 'package:upgrader/upgrader.dart';

Future<String?> getStoreVersion(String myAppBundleId) async {
  String? storeVersion;
  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    PlayStoreSearchAPI playStoreSearchAPI = PlayStoreSearchAPI();
    Document? result = await playStoreSearchAPI.lookupById(myAppBundleId, country: 'US');
    if (result != null) storeVersion = playStoreSearchAPI.version(result);
    log('PlayStore version: $storeVersion}');
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    ITunesSearchAPI iTunesSearchAPI = ITunesSearchAPI();
    Map<dynamic, dynamic>? result = 
                    await iTunesSearchAPI.lookupByBundleId(myAppBundleId, country: 'US');
    if (result != null) storeVersion = iTunesSearchAPI.version(result);
    log('AppStore version: $storeVersion}');
  } else {
    storeVersion = null;
  }
  return storeVersion;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this package -> [new_version](https://pub.dev/packages/new_version)
It's awesome & easy :)

```
///initialize your variable
    final newVersion = NewVersion(
      iOSId: 'com.google.Vespa',
      androidId: 'com.google.android.apps.cloudconsole',
    );
```

//and use this inside of your widget or controller

```
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        newVersion.showAlertIfNecessary(context: context);
        return Container();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try out [flutter_upgrade_version 1.1.3](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_upgrade_version) which support get Package Information, Information of Version on AppStore, Support In App Update - Android.

Details have been described in package

**Android**: Using the in-app updates feature is supported.

```dart
InAppUpdateManager manager = InAppUpdateManager();
AppUpdateInfo? appUpdateInfo = await manager.checkForUpdate();

/// Using `appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability` to check for update availability
```

**iOS**:  Using iTunes Search API to get the newest app version available on the stores.

```dart
PackageInfo _packageInfo = await PackageManager.getPackageInfo();

if (Platform.isIOS) {
  VersionInfo? _versionInfo2 = await UpgradeVersion.getiOSStoreVersion(
    packageInfo: _packageInfo, 
    regionCode: 'VN',  //RegionCode where your app will be available to purchase or download. 
  );
  ///Example: VN - Viet Nam
}
```